# Embed profile in separate Web site (WordPress)

Tags: wordpress, profile, forms

Is it possible to embed a profile (form) in a Web page on a different Web site?  My CiviCRM is on a WordPress site, so there is no "MORE" option to capture an HTML snippet when looking at the properties of my Profile.  I know I can embed the form in a Web page on the CiviCRM Web site, which inserts something like [civicrm component="profile" gid="33" mode="create" hijack="1"]

But obviously that alone won't work if I embed it on a page on another Web site.  Is there a way to do this?

[And if so, do I also need to set "Accept profile submissions from external sites" to yes?  Is this a security risk?]

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable a setting that allows Profile submissions from external sites for this option to be visible.

To do this go to Administer >> System Settings >> Misc and look for "Accept profile submissions from external sites"

Comment: Yes, I did that.  (Although CiviCRM did warn me that this is a security risk.)  But that doesn't tell me how to craft the link (in the external Web site).  Do I just include a tag like href="http://www.mymembershipsite.org civicrm component="profile" gid="33" mode="create" or what, exactly?

Comment: once you have turned on that option you should then see the link under More on the Profile

Comment: Of course!  Thanks!  (I was thrown off by the User Guide that made it seem that was only an option for non-WordPress installations.)

Copied, pasted...  Now, the form shows up on my remote site... But when I try to use it, I get the message "You do not have permission to access this content."

Any thoughts, O helpful ones??

Comment: "I was thrown off by the User Guide" can you give me a specific link so it can be updated